# What will be the order of statement execution in this use case?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Say I execute `select * from users` at t1 which gets finised at t3. At t2(in between t1 and t3) update comes for some of the records in users table say 
`update users set address='xyz'` where name = 'abc'. Will select statement acquire shared lock on all rows in advance or it will acquire for each row 
independently when it starts to read that row ?

My understanding is whosoever(among select or update) acquires the shared or exclusive lock earlier it will execute it other will wait ?

I am using Mysql innodb .

Comment: I think you need to read a bit more about the [MVCC model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).  You could do a **HUGE** `SELECT` over, say, a supermarket transactions table (sum of all customer purchases this week in Walmart. Then, I as a manager of branch X, **during** this transaction could modify a given record (say a refund) that is at the end of the list. The report will never "see" that update, because its committed transaction time is **later** than the start of the report! That's the essence of MVCC. Google mvcc mysql and check out Vlad Mihalcea's stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `transaction_isolation`.

It depends on whether the `SELECT` includes `FOR UPDATE` or `IN SHARE MODE`.

The `SELECT` is inside a transaction.  Normally, the `SELECT` will see the table as of the instant the transaction started.  Other queries may update/insert/delete rows that the `SELECT` is reaching for, but `SELECT` won't see them.  This puts a burden on InnoDB to keep old/new copies of row around for cases like this.

If you say `FOR UPDATE`, the other transaction will probably be delayed, awaiting the "intention to change" lock to be released.

Or it might lead to a deadlock.  InnoDB is good at seeing if the situation can't be resolved by waiting.

Perhaps you would like to discuss a specific case?

Comment: Its simple `Select` not `Select for Update`. Also we are not using any transactions explicitly, so it must be default.

Comment: Then, I think, you can run a long `SELECT` without stopping any writes.

Comment: I believe mysql will acquire the shared lock per row it is selecting at that instant instead of locking complete select range ? With this if write comes at the exactly same instant when read is happening for same row then write has to wait as exclusive lock can not be acquired with shared lock. Right ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "exactly same instant"; they will be in some order.

Comment: Ok thanks. What about my first question in last comment that mysql will acquire the shared lock per row it is selecting at that instant instead of locking complete select range ?

Comment: Rows will be locked (shared or exclusive or ..) one at a time, not all at the same instant.  The classic deadlock occurs when two connections ask for _exclusive_ locks on the same rows, but in a different order (and the queries run at the "same" time).